# Java: Fastest way to change brightness of an image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, brightness

I was wondering what the fastest way to alter the brightness of an image.  I have implemented the 'RescaleOp' method but I don't know if this is the fastest method or there are others.  Here is my implementation where I input an Image, change the brightness, and return an Image:

```
public static Image setBrightness(Image i) {
    BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    buff.createGraphics().drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
    RescaleOp op = new RescaleOp(brightness, offsets, null);
    BufferedImage buff1 = new BufferedImage(i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    buff1.createGraphics().drawImage(buff, op, 0, 0);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(buff1.getSource());
}
```

PS: I also need to convert the BufferedImage back into an Image because my computer doesn't like rendering BufferedImages.

Comment: "...because my computer doesn't like rendering BufferedImages." this makes no sense at all. Can you explain??

Comment: It lags horribly whenever I render more than 50 at a time. I am rendering over 2000 in my case.  But I only need to know how to change the image brightness in the fastest way possible so that doesn't really pertain very much to the question.

Comment: Then I would suggest that the optimal solution would be to simply control the number of BufferedImages you are rendering at one time.

Comment: That's an option I guess but I am rendering a landscape made of tiles and this would have defeated the point.  I guess I should have included that. Sorry

Comment: What is a range of scaleFactor and offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything I've read leads me to believe that RescaleOp is the best, fastest option